# How to construct a span from std::iota?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-span

The following works:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    auto view = std::vector<int>{0,1,2,3,4};
    auto s = std::span{view.begin(), view.end()};
    std::vector test(view.begin(), view.end());
}
```

But this does not:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    auto view = std::ranges::iota_view{0, 1000};
    auto s = std::span{view.begin(), view.end()};
    std::vector test(view.begin(), view.end());
}
```

The problem is, I have some generic code where I want to send it a range and then create a span over the range. I've tried sending in a `vector` and it is fine. The result from `iota` fails.

```
template <typename TRange>
requires std::ranges::random_access_range<TRange>
void Foo(TRange const & r)
{
     // The algorithm starts with a full span and then partitions
     auto s = std::span(r.begin(), r.end());
}
```

The code is being ported from boost, and there I would have used `boost::make_iterator_range()`, but my guess that this is superseded in the standard library by `std::span`. Is this right?

Answer (score 6):

You don't.

`std::span<int>` requires a contiguous range. `std::vector<int>` is a contiguous range, but `views::iota(0, 100)` is not contiguous, it's just random access.

---

Side-note: write `views::iota(0, 1000)`, don't write `ranges::iota_view{0, 1000}`. There is almost never any reason to write `ranges::meow_view` over `views::meow`, and it can easily be worse - the latter doesn't always give you something whose type is the former. Think of `meow_view` as an implementation detail.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Why do you need `subrange`? You're not even using it in your example.

Comment: I didn't include the whole example. Just stated that I needed a subrange. If it helps then I'm doing a recursive subdivision of a range algorithm and pushing subranges onto a stack. Douglas Peucker algorithm to be precise.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing "If it helps then" ... Well, it would help if you asked the question you actually have. If the question is "how do I get the first or second half of an arbitrary random-access view?" then the answer still isn't `ranges::subrange`, it's probably `views::take` or `views::drop`.

Comment: It wasn't the question I had when I wrote the question. I was just translating code I had from boost::make_iterator_range and assumed (wrongly) that std::span was the right thing. But thankyou. views::take and views::drop look like a better choice for the algorithm and will optimize better.

Comment: turns out that using ``take`` and ``drop`` is not ideal as I can't create a std::stack<T> where T represents the type of the *subrange*.  take of a take of a drop of a take builds a new type on each operation whereas doing the same thing with subrange it always returns the same type.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/79c4nWTEs

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I still have no idea what you're trying to do. And "take of a take of a drop of a take builds a new type on each operation" isn't necessarily true - calling the result of `v | take(0)` a `span` is pretty confusing because it's _not_ a `span`, but if you _made_ it one then `span1` would also be a `std::span`. And "subrange" only gives you the same type if you start from the same type of iterators, which you simply are by construction.

Comment: You don't need to know exactly what I'm doing. Suffice to say I have an input range that could be any random access range. It is subdivided and each subdivision is put into a stack. The subdivisions are removed from the stack and further subdivided. It has to be ensured that the operations to subdivide a subdivision always returns the same type. std::ranges::subrange does this. std::views::take and std::views::drop do not.

Comment: If you are interested the algorithm is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm But I'm not doing it recursively I'm using a stack to keep track of the subdivisions. The algorithm works fine and has been doing so for years. The only requirement was to change from boost::make_iterator_range to something equivalent.

Comment: The actual implementation is https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/c14fbaa73e7fd3e18a9e3df40696ef2f

Answer (score 1):

The thing I'm looking for is not `std::span` but `std::ranges::subrange`, which is more generic, and works with non-contiguous memory.

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    auto view = std::views::iota(0, 1000);
    auto s = std::ranges::subrange{view.begin(),view.end()};
    std::vector test(view.begin(), view.end());
}
```